# Having difficulty with my JS/jQuery creating a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm making a little post it web app just to learn JavaScript and jQuery because I was told it would be a good practice project, so I'm having a couple of errors here and have no clue how to fix them. I'm new to StackOverflow -- I use it more as a reference than anything.

This is the code:
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=67i5HwY5

The problem:
-When adding multiple post-its it messes up the div..

I have ideas of how to fix it, I just am also new to jQuery and JS so I dont know how to apply them. If you guys could help me out, that'd be great.

Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/mitchbregs/fYTFV/5/

Comment: Hi, You are adding to many code, to help you I recommend you to create a live example in http://www.jsfiddle.net/ and some of relevant code, not the entire application

Comment: Welcome to SO. A little piece of advice, try setting up a working example in jsFiddle with the code you have, rather then posting a ton of code and letting us searc h for the issue. Also try to explain what you mean by 'messing-up'

Comment: Also, really helpful if you could separate out all the css and styling and slim down the example to just the part of your code that isn't behaving correctly.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tips. I added it to jsFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/mitchbregs/rQB2v/6/ -- By messing up, I mean there is some sort of glitch occuring..

Comment: If you look at the full screen result, try adding a post it twice and you will see the problem.

Comment: Let me know if my answer helps you, Mitchell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/mattblancarte/fYTFV/12/

You basically need to add a unique identifier to each of those post-it notes. :) In this case, I just augmented the ID you are using, then incremented the id each time you make a new post-it note.

You may want to cache those selectors, too... Instead of using $("#postIt-" + id) over and over, just do:

```
var postit = $("#postIt-" + id);
postit.css();
```

You can also pass in all of your css within one method, like so:

```
postit.css({
  'background' : 'blue',
  'height' : '100px',
  //etc.
});
```

Comment: sorry, im just new to this haha i upvoted and accepted.. thanks again!

Comment: No worries, @Mitchell. :) Glad I could help you get this sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like

```
$("#header").append("<div id='urlPost'
```

might be causing a problem? appending multiple items with the same ID usually isn't good. Each postit will need a unique identifier.

maybe create a global variable called 'id' and set to 0.

then your click function can look like:

```
$("#header").append("<div id='urlPost" + id + "' class='etc'");

$("#urlPost"+id).css("width",wh);
```

then at the end of the function:

```
id++;
```

This way each time you add a new post, css is only applied to the newest one.

Comment: @petersmith i just tried making it into a class instead of id. It kind of solved the problem, but now instead of making other post its, it reuses the original making multiple post its disabled.

Comment: Removed suggestion to make a class, because your postits will actually need to be unique in this case.

Comment: @petersmith, thanks for the suggestion.. i tried to apply what you told me and im getting problems http://jsfiddle.net/mitchbregs/fYTFV/9/

Comment: You'll need to declare id outside the click function, try on the first line even before $(document).ready(function(){})

Answer (score 0):

Hey just to answer your question..
i made a solution using only jquery.This could be another solution where you wont need to declare a var.
Here it is..http://jsfiddle.net/vwPDr/

i used :last selector of jquery and applied it to draggble class. check it out.